# Trying to kill a nohup process that changes PIDs

Tags: kill, pid, nohup

I list the PID and then try to kill it using:

```
nohup server &
kill <PID>
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
nohup: failed to run command ‘server’: No such file or directory
```

[image]

This is because the PID keeps changing! **When I try to kill the current PID, the nohup process is suddenly another PID**! *Below is a screenshot of the process continually chainging PIDs.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you quite understand the error message.

[`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) just launches another process (in your example called `server`), preventing it from getting a SIGHUP once the terminal starting it disconnects.

The problem here is not that the PID changes (the displayed pid is the pid of `nohup` when it temporarily launches), it's that `nohup` can't find a command called `server` to launch at all.

> nohup: failed to run command ‘server’: No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks Joachim! That makes more sense. How is the correct way to find the PID of a process I launched by calling "nohup python test.py &"

Comment: @AllieCat At least on linux, once you do `nohup <processname>`, you can use `$!` (`echo $!`/`kill $!`/...) in the shell to work with the pid. Normally, you'd echo it to a file so you can use it later.

Answer (score 1):

Your process is not continually changing PIDs, you're repeatedly starting the process and it's getting a new PID each time.

```
nohup server &
```

Starts the program `nohup` and tells it to launch `server`. When `nohup` can't find `server`, it prints the error message you see and quits, hence the

```
Exit 127    nohup server
```

messages you keep seeing.